# Chainlink Node - Your node is operating close to its maximum capacity and may start to miss jobs

Tags: nodes, lag, chainlink

While trying to run a `chainlink node` im getting the error:

> [INFO]  HeadTracker: Head 19913141 is lagging behind, there are 3 more
> heads in the queue. Your node is operating close to its maximum
> capacity and may start to miss jobs. services/head_tracker.go:90
>
> [ERROR] HeadTracker: dropping head 19913138 with hash
> 0xcbeef62885457ddb821b9024118e6585ac04191bf697ef37f74e05d70cf8372f
> because queue is full. WARNING: Your node is overloaded and may start
> missing jobs. logger/default.go:139
> stacktrace=github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/logger.Error
>
> /chainlink/core/logger/default.go:117
>
> github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/logger.Errorf
>
> /chainlink/core/logger/default.go:139
>
> github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/services.(*headRingBuffer).run
>
> /chainlink/core/services/head_tracker.go:105

Anyone knows whats causing the node to lag behind or how to find out?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually due to a bad `ETH_URL`, you'll want to use something other than the ETH_URL you're using, or, you have a slow connection to your Ethereum/Matic/Polygon/Avalanche/etc node